# How to edit Row Value of Column in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

i have got the values of my datatable using the following method

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table = GetTable();
string expression;
expression = "B.Id = " + textBox1.Text;
DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = table.Select(expression);
for (int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i++)
{

    sno.Text = foundRows[i][1].ToString();
    name.Text = foundRows[i][2].ToString();
    dcn.Text = foundRows[i][3].ToString();
    stat.Text = foundRows[i][4].ToString();
}
```

so how do i change the value of `foundRows[i][4]`

Comment: What do you think `[0]` means?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Only if I want to. Consider that I've been here longer than you have, and I have a better idea of how it works.

Comment: @SyedAliNaqi: stackoverflow must be managed by moderators which are also users. These users spend a lot of their free time f.e. fixing other users questions, so they are already doing their work. Because of the moderator tools they are notified but they often cannot answer the question itself. Conclusion: do not blame people who are trying to help, regardless of whether they answer your question or not.

Comment: Also, you have  changed the question radically. Now my already accepted answer has no relation to it anymore(thanks for that, always ask a _new_ question in that case), now it is even a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the [`DataRow`'s indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the first column, so i don't understand the problem. If you want to access the second field use `foundRows[i][1]`:

```
MessageBox.Show(foundRows[i][1].ToString());
```

If you want to loop all fields:

```
for(int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i ++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < table.Columns.Count; c++)
        MessageBox.Show(foundRows[i][c].ToString());
}
```

I suggest to use the strongly typed `Field`-extension method which also supports nullable types.

```
MessageBox.Show(foundRows[i].Field<string>(0));
```

Comment: but can u also tell me how i can change the value of for example this foundRows[i][1]

Comment: You can either use the setter: `foundRows[i][1] = "New Value"` or use `SetField`: `foundRows[i].SetField(1, "New Value")`

Comment: well i tried but it isn't working the value doesn't changes

Comment: @SyedAliNaqi:  maybe you need to ask another question since that should work.

Comment: @SyedAliNaqi: you should not edit your question in a way that makes my answer useless for future readers. Instead ask another question as i have suggested.

Comment: i tried to ask another question but it gave me a 2 hour time limit.

Comment: You should be able to ask another question, users with less than 125 reputation have a limit, you can ask another question every 20 minutes, 6 in 24 hours at a maximum.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask

Comment: well i tried and there was time limit of more than an hour and i need it really bad...

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table = GetTable();
string expression;
expression = "B.Id = " + textBox1.Text;
DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = table.Select(expression);
for (int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i++)
{

sno.Text = foundRows[i][1].ToString();
name.Text = foundRows[i][2].ToString();
dcn.Text = foundRows[i][3].ToString();
stat.Text = foundRows[i][4].ToString();
}


DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = GetTable();
    string expression;
    expression = "B.Id = "+textBox1.Text;
    DataRow[] foundRows;
    foundRows = table.Select(expression);
    for(int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i ++)
    {
     if(button1.Text == "Make Preasent!")
     {
         foundRows[i][4] = true;
        table.AcceptChanges();
     }
     else
     {
         foundRows[i].SetField(4, false);
         table.AcceptChanges();
     }
    }
```